# C++: Returning a templated object from a class, template type mismatch?

Tags: c++, templates, types, return, mismatch

I have the following source code with a compiler error. Its obvious what I'm trying to do so I won't try explaining besides by saying that the type `node<N>*` being returned is not the correct type because it is a template and thats creating a conflict with the `session*` object. Heres the error.

```
linked_list_1.cpp|17|error: cannot convert 'node<session*>*' to 'session*' in assignment|
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg whether it is allocated on the stack or on the heap should not make a difference. He is correctly allocating (although not deleting it correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 17, you want to assign the return value of `return_node` to a `session*`, but the return type of `return_node` is a `Node<N>*` (`Node<Session*>*`) and not a `N` (`session*`).
Add an accessor function to the node class, and use it to access the data member, e.g:

```
session* SESSION_COPY;
SESSION_COPY =  LIST->return_node(0)->getData();
```

Comment: In the node class, add a function `N getData() { return data; }` that lets you access the data object.

Comment: The `N data;` member stores the pointer. N in your case, is a `session *`. Btw, unless you are doing this for learning templates, use `std::list` or `std::forward_list`.

Comment: Is your push_back method working correctly? this usually means that you are accessing an object that is not valid in memory (not allocated or has been deleted).

Answer (score 1):

Because the `return_node` function returns `node<N>*` and not `N`. Or when `N` is substituted with the template argument: `return_node` returns `node<session*>*` (look in the header file) but you try to assign the returned pointer to a `session*` variable. Just like the error message *very clearly* says.

Comment: @lost_with_coding If `return_node` is indeed supposed to be public, then you might want to add a function to the `node` class to return the contained data. Then you could do e.g. `session* s = list.return_node(0)->data();`